# Proguard deletes method parameters

Tags: android, android-proguard

Recently I found very strange thing with ProGuard. I have this code snippet [image: code snippet]

As you can see, method *showTipHoodLock* takes 2 parameters, *fragmentManager* and *top* (some offset)

but after I compile the app with *minifyEnabled* **true**

I got this on click callback [image: onClick callback]

and this is *Utils.showTipHoodLock* method 
[image: showTipHoodLock]

As you can see, proguard deleted 2nd parameter (named **top**) from method signature and replaced its occurances with **0** literal.

Is it a bug, or a feature, or did I miss something?

**P.S.** If I change values in line

```
int coords[] = {0, 0}
```

to any other numbers, then everything works perfect, and nothing is deleted. Moreover The same snippet of code (which is copy-pasted) in different part of application (in other fragment), starts to work.

Comment: try `-keepattributes Signature` and it shouldn't happen anymore. also, feel free to post your proguard ruleset so we can see why it's doing that.

Comment: I have this in rules

Comment: have you tried toggling the `-verbose` mode to tell you why it's removing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a bug, or a feature, or did I miss something?

This is **NOT** a bug, this is a **feature** to optimise your code.

According to your piece of code, the second parameter is referenced by following logic as **READ ONLY** and its value is **FIXED** to be **0**.

Proguard will remove (a kind of Proguard optimisation: **Remove unused parameters** or **Propagate constant arguments**) this parameter with this **KNOWN FIXED** value to simplify the invocation flow.

Comment: Well I assumed that. But why when I change array initial values to any other values different from 0 it starts to work fine.

Comment: This is related to how you implement  Utils.showTipHoodLock method. If proguard “sees” that this argument is actually able to be replaced with a constant value, then the said optimization will take place

Comment: Proguad analyses  your code as a whole, if it sees any opportunity to improve/ simplify the logic and / or generated byte code, it will take actions. Propagating constant argument is one of such optimization’s.

Comment: But it seems like it's a bug. It's the way how getLocationOnScreen method works, it takes an array, which it fulfills with values. I know that is not best way to implement method that returns values via paratemters. But it's a part of how java allows me to do.

Comment: There are many this kind of “bugs”, as you call them. You can explicitly preserve this particular class or method by add a “-keep xxxx” configuration inside your proguard congfig file so that this particular class / method will not be optimized by proguard